# Paste but keep Destination formatting

Tags: excel, vba

hi newbie here but remember you were once also. im having trouble heres my code but its keeping the sheet 1 text format when i want it to be like sheet 2 text and cell format

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A4").SpecialCells(xlConstants).copy 
Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A4").End(xlUp)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: Record a macro that pastes special values only.  Then view it's code.  start recording: copy a value right click on target select paste special values.  stop recording view macro.  Recording a macro is often doing what you want is often the easiest way to see how to program it

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `PasteSpecial` - here's he code cleaned up:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: @jermey that didn't work the original sheet1 text color and size stayed. and ruined the original code because on sheet 2 i still had spaces

Answer (score 0):

If so, don't use copy, but set value to destination:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim k As Range
    Set k = Range("Sheet1!A1:A4")
    Range("Sheet2!A1:A4").Value = k.Value
End Sub
```